# webapi restful routing not working

Tags: c#, rest, routes

I have this Web API route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "CustomerSearchApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{criteria}",
           defaults: new { criteria = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

This works:

```
http://localhost/api/CustomerSearch/Search?criteria=sdasd
```

This does not:

```
http://localhost/api/CustomerSearch/Search/sdasd
```

This is my CustomerSearchController signature:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Search(string criteria)
```

Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: What version of asp.net web api are you using?

Comment: system.web.http version 5.1.0.0

Comment: Maybe can help you: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that, but I am on VS2012 and this requires VS2013 for some reason. But maybe I will have to bite the bullet and just upgrade.